# Let $ABC$ be a well-defined product of matrices. Suppose that $A,C$ are both invertible. Prove that $rank(ABC)=rank(B)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Not sure where to go with this... I've done the following, though:

> $A$ and $C$ must be square matrices if they are invertible. Let $A$ be an $m\times m$ matrix, and let $C$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. Let $B$ be a $m\times n$ matrix so that $ABC$ is well defined.
>
> $A$ has a rank of $m$ and $C$ has a rank of $n$. $rank(AB)\leq m$ and $rank(AB)\leq rank(B)$ Also, $rank(BC)\leq n$ and $rank(BC)\leq rank(B)$.

From here, I have no idea what to do. I don't even know if I'm on the right track. The best I can figure is that $rank(ABC)\leq \min(rank(A),rank(B),rank(C))$, but I have no idea how to show that $rank(ABC)=rank(B)$.

Comment: Which is your definition of "rank" of a matrix?

Comment: @AgustíRoig What do you mean? "rank" is the dimension of the column space... so if $A$ and $C$ are invertible, and $A$ is an $m\times m$ matrix, then the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, meaning the dimensions of the column space is $m$, thus the rank of $A$ is $m$... simmilarly for $C$.

Comment: Well, you could have defined "rank" by means of reduced matrices... Anyway, see my answer.

Comment: @AgustíRoig Ahh.. I think I see how I might do this, then... If $A$ and $C$ are invertible, they can be reduced to $I$... and $I$ has the same rank as $A$ and $C$. So if I have the product $I_mBI_n$, then I get $B$...

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this isn't flawed... but it seems like it should be correct...

> If $A$ and $C$ are invertible, they must be square matrices. Let $A$ be an $m\times m$ matrix, $B$ be an $m\times n$ matrix, and $C$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. $rank(A)=m$ and $rank(C)=n$.
>
> Since $A$ and $C$ are invertible, they can be reduced via Gaussian Elimination to their respective identity matrices $I_{m}$ and $I_{n}$ respectively, both of which have the same rank: $rank(I_{m})=m$ and $rank(I_{n})=n$. Consider the new matrix product
>   \begin{align*}
> I_{m}BI_{n}=B
> \end{align*}
>   which has the same rank as
>   \begin{align*}
> ABC
> \end{align*}
>   Therefore, $rank(ABC)=rank(I_{m}BI_{n})=rank(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

So, if $b_1, \dots , b_n$ are the columns of $B$,

$$
\mathrm{rank}\ B = \mathrm{dim}\ \mathbf{span} (b_1, \dots , b_n) \ .
$$

Also you can see that the columns of $AB$ are

$$
Ab_1, \dots , Ab_n \ .
$$

Hence, if $A$ is invertible, multiplication by $A$ is an isomorphism and

$$
\mathrm{dim}\ \mathbf{span} (Ab_1, \dots , Ab_n) = \mathrm{dim}\ \mathbf{span} (b_1, \dots , b_n) \ .
$$

Alternatively you can show easily, just with the definition of linearly independent vectors and a short computation that, if $A$ is invertible, then

$$
b_1, \dots , b_n \quad \text{are l.i.}\qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad Ab_1, \dots , Ab_n \quad \text{are l.i.} \ .
$$

Anyway,

$$
\mathrm{rank}\ AB = \mathrm{rank}\ B \ .
$$